# serverless NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve

Tags: javascript, webpack, serverless

Hi I can't deploy a serverless api. got this error when trying to deploy

I trying to update npm and serverless, remove all webpack in package.json use to try if it can create problems. Nothing works !

```
$ sls deploy --region $REGION --stage $STAGE
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Serverless: Bundling with Webpack...
assets by status 1.55 KiB [cached] 16 assets

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

ERROR in NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created.

webpack 5.73.0 compiled with 16 errors in 38 ms
 
 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  Webpack compilation error, see stats above
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              14.19.1
     Framework Version:         2.72.3 (local)
     Plugin Version:            5.5.4
     SDK Version:               4.3.2
     Components Version:        3.18.2
```

If you allready got this error, thanks to help !